# Ubuntu Server WIFI Configuration

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-gnome

I just installed Ubuntu Server (latest from ubuntu website). I successfully installed the OS on my laptop. Now how to install GUI?

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome

sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install
```

It gives error "Unable to locate package gnome".

Is it due to network connection? I cannot enable my wireless card externally (From keyboard). When I try ping command it says "unknown host".

Thank you.

Comment: No. Not working. Gives same error "Unable to locate package".

Comment: Can I install the GNOME package offline, like downloading the package separately and burning on CD or USB?

Comment: apt-cache search gnome | grep "^ubuntu" . Check the output that you have available package for gnome-desktop.

Comment: I made some changes in description. Please refer to that. But I found the solution. Read the solution in **Answers** section.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install the packages?

Comment: Yes. Its working now. I posted the answer in **Answers** section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I finally found the reason behind the problem. My wireless card was not working because I had never configured it. During the installation of the OS I had skipped the wireless card configuration process.
So the solution is to configure the wireless card while installation.

After the complete installation, while connecting to the access point, I encountered a problem, which I like to discuss, along with the solution.

Initially, the card is on off state. To wake it up, we type

`ifconfig interface_name up`

Where "interface_name" is the name of your wireless card. For different systems, the name varies. To get the name for your system, type `iwconfig`

You may encounter an error "Error:Operation not possible due to RF-Kill"

This is because your wireless card is been disabled externally.To overcome this error, without typing any other command press the WIFI button your keyboard. After you press the button, type `ifconfig interface_name up` again. Your Wifi will be in active state.

To connect to available networks follow this [link](https://bhattigurjot.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/connect-to-wi-fi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal/)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Gnome Desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: No. Not working. Unable to locate package.