# Internet not working Ubuntu 16

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet

I just finished a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16 server. I was able to do the installation with WiFi connection. After the installation the WiFi can't connect, then I plug in a Cable, the light is blinking but the internet does not work.

> Ping returned "unknown host".

Try installing, but get this error unable to fetch archives.
Dual boot Thinkpad t410.

Comment: Try this and provide the output of `ifconfig -a`.  Please provide full version (i.e., 16.04 or 16.10, the latter is already available in daily build for instance).

Comment: Please give the output of  `lspci`. Since there have been problems with Broadcom device in Linux distros.

Comment: They said I need a reputation above 10 to post images. Can someone help me with 10points pls

Comment: You do not need to post any images.

Comment: You describing one or two problems but what exactly your question?

Comment: You can post text files and program output listings as text, not as images. To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It seems that your wifi is configured but is at sleep. This is because your wireless card is switched off externally.

You need to type some commands in terminal. If you have installed GUI, then open the terminal by pressing `ctrl+alt+T` and follow the steps below. And if not, skip this terminal process and type directly.

In all the steps, skip "{ }" these braces and replace it with the parameter specified inside it.

**Steps:-**

- Restart your system.
- Login as your personal or root account.
- Without typing any command press the WIFI button on your keyboard.
- After you press the button, type `ifconfig {interface_name} up`.

**Note:** The "interface_name" in above command have to be replaced with the name of wireless card which your system has. To get the name of the interface type `iwconfig` and hit enter. In my case the name of the interface is "wlo1". It will be something similar like that.

- In some cases, still the wifi will be off. In that case press the wifi button on keyboard again.

Your Wifi will be in active state.

To connect to your WIFI network, follow these steps:

- Type `ifconfig {interface_name}` and press Enter.
- Type `iwconfig {interface_name} essid {name_of_the_WIFI_network} key {password_of_WIFI}` and press Enter. If your wireless network does not require a security key, skip the key. If you see an error with respect to the key, then remove the password of your WIFI and skip the key.

Comment: I don't have a GUI , its fresh Ubuntu server 16.04 I install, after installation, can't no internet is working, I have inspected the WiFi key but nothing is happening

Comment: Is your wireless card configured? after `ifconfig {interface_name} up` type `ifconfig {interface_name}`. If you get some details with respect to your wireless card then it is. If you get any error message, that means it is not configured.

Comment: I also had the same problem for the first time when I installed the server. At the end I found the solution. Follow this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/833445/ubuntu-server-wifi-configuration)